# UI elements freeze despite webworker

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I am working on a simple sorting algorithm demo app. I have a few sorting algorithms written in JavaScript, and an HTML page to try them out. I have tested the algorithms separately and they work fine.

You can input your own array, or a random one can be generated for you. If the size of the array was too large, whether you were generating it or sorting it, this would hang the UI, so I added a webworker that performs these operations in a separate thread.

The app logs what it is doing. Before the web worker, when working with really large arrays the log would appear all of a sudden only after the process was completed, but thanks to the webworker, logs appear as soon as each individual step is completed. Also, the page remains scrollable, while without the worker everything would freeze until the job was done.

Having delegated the computationally heavy elements to the webworker, I was expecting elements on the page to remain fully interactive, but this doesn't seem to be the case. All buttons etc on the page become unresponsive anyway. To be exact, they stay interactive for a really short while and then freeze--for example, if I mouseover a button, the cursor will change shape, but then it will stay frozen in that shape no matter where I move it, and if I click, the click won't register until after the webworker has done its job. This is a problem, because I have 'stop' buttons the user may click to stop the webworker if it is taking too long to generate an array or sort it. As things stand, the stop buttons freeze, and if you click them, this will have an effect only after the worker has finished anyway, effectively making them useless.

How can I make sure my controls on the page remain usable? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

So, I ran into what I think is the same problem, and was having a bear of a time with it for days.  Thankfully I ran across this: https://nolanlawson.com/2016/02/29/high-performance-web-worker-messages/

For some reason it seems on both Chrome and Firefox, when webworkers post messages, it freezes the main thread when in the process of packing the data.

If you use JSON to fully serialize all of your objets when posting messages, it seems to make everything run much, much more smoothly.